# Prove or disprove the following proposition $L_1^*∪L_2^*⊆(L_1∪L_2)^*$

Tags: formal-languages, automata

$L_1^*∪L_2^*⊆(L_1∪L_2)^*$

I actually disproved the opposite proposition $[(L_1∪L_2)^*⊆L_1^*∪L_2^*]$ and my intuition tells me that this is actually true... I tried to show that the combinations of words in the right group $[(L_1∪L_2)^*]$ obviously contain all the words from the left group $[L_1^*∪L_2^*]$ and it's also very plain to see, but I have no idea how to formalize it.

Any idea how to formally prove it?
Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Is $L_1^* \subseteq (L_1 \cup L_2)^*$?

Comment: It is. But how can I show it formally?

Comment: By the definition of set inclusion ($A \subseteq B$): take an arbitrary element in $A$, and show it exists also in $B$... For the above statement, this is quite trivial, not?

Comment: But we're talking about infinite groups... How can I show that ALL the elements in $L_1^*$ are also in $(L_1∪L_2)^*$?

Comment: The size of $L_1^*$ is irrelevant. The proof means: "give me some $x\in L_1^*$, and I will show you that $x\in (L_1 \cup L_2)^*$. And this is true **for every $x\in L_1^*$**.   OK, if this is still unclear, let's continue in the [chat] room.

Comment: Your title is not very informative.

Answer (score 2):

This is true. 
You only have to prove the following staments:

1. if $A\subseteq B$ then $A^{*} \subseteq B^{*}$,
2. If $A\subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq C$ then $A \cup B \subseteq C$.

We know $L_1 \subseteq L_1 \cup L_2$ for 1. we can conclude $L_1^{*} \subseteq (L_1 \cup L_2)^{*}$, analogously $L_2^{*} \subseteq (L_1 \cup L_2)^{*}$. For 2. we can conclude $L_1^{*} \cup L_2^{*} \subseteq (L_1 \cup L_2)^{*}$.